# Ubuntu boot halts

Tags: boot

After the Ubuntu logo the boot halts and all i see is this:

- Stopping anac(h)ronistic cron
- Stopping save Kernel messages
- Checking battery state
- Stopping System V runlevel comaptibility
- Starting CUPS printing spooler/server

And then it jsut hangs there forever. Any help? I've tried previous kernel versions from Grub with no success

Comment: Sounds like Video Card/Chip issue. What do you run?

Comment: AMD Radeon HD 3450, this system has been working fine for 2 months with the Ubuntu drivers.

Comment: Boots fine from the LiveCD

Comment: I was under the impression it was a fresh install today. Sorry.

Comment: Don't apologize! Just tell me you ahve some bright idea for what the problem might be. Please.

Answer (score -1):

Boot off your LiveCD and run:

```
sudo touch /forcefsck
```

And reboot.

Comment: Negative. I would say now it's worse, before it used to keep the screen resolution, now in the middle of the screen in a quirky font it says:

* Checking Battery State

Any bresh ideas?

Comment: I have everything backed up. I'm compelled to just reinstall everything.

Comment: I would. Sometimes it's a lot quicker. =)